# Content script injection in manifest v3 not as fast as in v2

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have ported my manifest v2 extension to v3 and have run into a small issue ...

My current extension re-defines the window.navigator.userAgent property via an inline script that's loaded at document_start:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.textContent = *inline code*;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

It works quite good, however in v3 since inline scripts are not allowed, my content script loads an external .js file in the exact same spot passing the required variables of what the user agent should be, etc.,- however I'm noticing it's not loading fast enough and it's not overriding window.navigator.userAgent on certain websites:

```
script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(*external .js file*);
```

I'm wondering if there's any better way of handling this without resorting to dispatchEvent, which is what I'm doing right now:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("onsecuritypolicyviolation", *inline code*);
document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("securitypolicyviolation"));
```

From the timing measurements I've done, the external script loads approx. 100ms after the inline one from dispatchEvent.

Comment: Don't use a script element via `src` because it's inherently asynchronous and will run after the scripts in the html. Use `"world":"MAIN"` in manifest.json or chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts with the same, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72607832).

Comment: Thanks, I separated that part of the code and loaded via manifest world:MAIN, and added a cookie from background to pass a variable to the content script, works good!